Why does Webflow reset all the styles I set after switching between breakpoints
So I adjust the relative positioning of the hero text element in percentages.
I switch from the desktop breakpoint to the mobile breakpoint and then switch back and non of the styles are applied. Why is this happening? 
I've made sure that all the classes are unique and I've added in extra combo classes.
If anyone could help I would be really grateful!!!
